# Find the number of possible functions $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that $f(m\times n)=f(m)f(n)$ for every $m,n\in S$ and $m\times n\in S$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Then find the number of possible functions $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that $f(m\times n)=f(m)f(n)$ for every $m,n\in S$ and $m\times n\in S$.

Can there be functions other than $f(x)=x^2$. I think one needs to consider the cases when $n=1$ and when $n\neq1$

Comment: $f(x)=x$ also works I guess

Comment: Note that $x^2$ doesn't map to $S$

Comment: You won't have a simple algebraic formula for your function. to be $f:S\to S$.  I gave you a starting point below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to worry about the assignations where $m\times n$ stays in $S$,  the combinations that do that are $1\times 1$ through $1\times 7$,   $2\times 2$ and $2\times 3$

If $f(1)=1$ that takes care of all of those cases and you just need $f(2)=1$ or $f(2)=2$ to stay inside the $2\times 2$ bound   If $f(2)=1$, $f(3)$ can be anything, so you have 7 cases there.    If $f(2)=2$ then $f(3)$ has to be between $1$ and $3$,  so 3 choices there.  So for $f(1)=1, f(2)=1$ we have 5 free choices amongst 7 objects,  $7^5$.   $f(1)=1, f(2)=2$ we have 4 free choices of 7 and one choice amongst 3,  so $3\cdot 7^4$.

As $f(1)$ increases, that decreases the range of possible values for everything else.  If $f(1)=2$,  then nothing else can have a value above 3.   If $f(1)=3$ then nothing else can have a value above 2.  If $f(1)\geq 4$, then the only values everything else can have is 1.

Can you finish from here?